# Web service for a Hybrid mobile App

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating a Hybrid mobile app that will read data from data-source and update it's tables.
Now , the question is how/what to use to provide data-source to hybrid app.
I want to avoid taking a hosting and create a REST based API for app.
Is there any other alternative to this situation.
Kindly reply.

Comment: You can use something like Firebase to have a remote DB that you can GET from and POST.

Comment: @AbhishekJain , thank you for your response, i checked firebase it seem very handy plateform. Do you any that can guide me for setup